# self.navigationController == nil after awaking from LocalNotification

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uilocalnotification

I'm working in Xcode 4.3.2

I implemented `Local Notifications` that alert the user of a new event at a predetermined time. So when my app is in the background and the clock strikes 8 am (for instance), the user will get a notification from my app.

When the user decides to view the app from the background I load a nib. Currently, this nib works properly: it shows the view as it was it arranged in the nib. However, after the nib is shown to the user, I want to forward the user to a different view in the `LocalNotificationsHandler.m`. When I attempt to push the second view, my app fails. So while there isn't an error message, it seems the second nib will not load.

In short the flow goes as follows:

- user gets notification while my app is running in the background
- user chooses to view the app
- the `LocalNotificationsHandler nib` will load
- `self.navigationController == nil` (in LocalNotificationsHandler.m)
- self.navigationController will not "[pushViewController: "new view" animated:YES]" to get a new view

I'm wondering if there is something I'm missing from my AppDelegate.m file so I've included 
"didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" from my AppDelegate.m file:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    // Add the navigation controller's view to the window and display.


    NSLog(@"did finish launching with options");
    [self.window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];

  if (self.locationManager == nil)
  {
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.purpose = @"We will try to use you location";
  }

  if([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled])
  {
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
  }

  self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = nil;

  return YES;
}
```

Comment: Is the UINavigationController non-nil if you load the app normally (ie, not from a local notification)?  In my experience the load process should be identical but for the options in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:.  My instinct is that the UINavigationController might not be getting instantiated at all, even normally?

Comment: No, it's not normally nil. How should I check that the UINavigationController is getting instantiated?

Comment: I use storyboard instead of nibs, so I'm not 100% sure.  I just think that what might be happening is that you're loading from the nib, which loads the single VC, but not the background UINavigationController.  Have you tried creating it if it's missing?  (ie if (!self.navigationController) { self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:yourVCInstance] } )

Comment: Could we see the code that creates the Local Notification Handler? That looks like its more likely to be the culprit than the didFinishLaunching method. Essentially, what's going wrong is that the Local Notification Handler doesn't exist on a navigation stack. So to fix the issue, you need to work out what's meant to be pushing it onto the stack in the first place (Is it programmatic? Is it supposed to be done by a storyboard? XIB maybe? e.t.c.).

Answer (score 1):

You are using the outdated (since iOS 3) method of adding the viewcontroller's view to the main UIWindow. That should be looking like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // create properly sized window
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    // create instance of root VC and assign to window
    MainViewController *vc = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
    self.window.rootViewController = vc;
    [vc release];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

The navigationController property of a view controller is ONLY set if it is actually presented from a UINavigationController.

See this writeup for more information: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/11/revisited/

Comment: Nice article. Not sure if it solves the problem, but well worth a read.